# Swift - required method not implemented: -[JSQMessagesViewController collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am migrating an iOS app to Swift 3 and I keep having this error message on my ChatViewController.

```
2017-02-21 16:40:40.599 Jaco[52613:2864859] *** Assertion failure in -[Jaco.ChatViewController collectionView:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:], /Users/Royal/dev/jab/ios/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m:491
2017-02-21 16:40:40.609 Jaco[52613:2864859] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ERROR: required method not implemented: -[JSQMessagesViewController collectionView:messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:]'
```

Here is part of my code

```
  // DATA SOURCE 1
  func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                      messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let data = self.messages[indexPath.item]
    return data
  }


  // DATA SOURCE 2
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                               numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
  }
```

I tried adding "override" but the error message is still there.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView
```

to

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView
```